# bash: g++: command not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu, g++

I am installing a package on R, which needs g++ command. 
My laptop is running ubuntu 18.04.3. 
All g++, gpp, gcc are installed, but I cannot call g++ from the terminal. 
I googled around and found that everyone told to install build-essential and g++ those I already have. 
How can I solve this kind of error? How can I get my g++ back from the terminal? 
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBEnM.png)

Comment: Look at your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Show output of command: "dpkg -l | grep g++"

Comment: @Nic3500 here is my path.
bash: /usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/alexbeatson/bin:/home/alexbeatson/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/alexbeatson/jdk1.8.0_131/bin:/home/alexbeatson/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin:

Comment: @Šerg It has four g++ 1) g++ (2) g++-6 (3) g++-7 and (4) g++-8. apt install on g++ and g++-8 doesn't work.

Comment: ls -la /usr/bin/g++

Comment: I think it will help you: "sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++"

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall g++ using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++
```

Now you'll be able to call g++ from the terminal:

```
yacine@yacine:$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```